# Evaluate moving last 5 orders created by each ID

Tags: sql, database, presto

I have the following table:

```
create table DemoTable
(
   buyer_id INT,
   order_id INT,
   variable_a INT,
   created_date datetime
);

INSERT INTO DemoTable(buyer_id, order_id, variable_a, created_date) VALUES (54, 75, 609, '2019-06-02 16:46:53');
INSERT INTO DemoTable(buyer_id, order_id, variable_a, created_date) VALUES (54, 74, 363, '2019-06-01 22:00:00');
INSERT INTO DemoTable(buyer_id, order_id, variable_a, created_date) VALUES (54, 73, 300, '2019-06-01 20:00:02');
INSERT INTO DemoTable(buyer_id, order_id, variable_a, created_date) VALUES (54, 72, 225, '2019-06-01 18:12:03');
INSERT INTO DemoTable(buyer_id, order_id, variable_a, created_date) VALUES (54, 71, 110, '2019-06-01 16:10:03');
INSERT INTO DemoTable(buyer_id, order_id, variable_a, created_date) VALUES (54, 55, 213, '2019-06-01 14:22:03');
INSERT INTO DemoTable(buyer_id, order_id, variable_a, created_date) VALUES (54, 51, 225, '2018-12-01 16:12:03');
INSERT INTO DemoTable(buyer_id, order_id, variable_a, created_date) VALUES (54, 32, 110, '2018-12-01 15:10:03');
INSERT INTO DemoTable(buyer_id, order_id, variable_a, created_date) VALUES (54, 12, 213, '2018-12-01 12:22:03');
```

| buyer_id | order_id | variable_a | created_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 54 | 75 | 609 | 2019-06-02 16:46:53 |
| 54 | 74 | 363 | 2019-06-01 22:00:00 |
| 54 | 75 | 300 | 2019-06-01 20:00:02 |
| 54 | 73 | 225 | 2019-06-01 18:12:03 |
| 54 | 72 | 110 | 2019-06-01 16:10:03 |
| 54 | 55 | 213 | 2019-06-01 14:22:03 |
| 54 | 51 | 225 | 2018-12-01 16:12:03 |
| 54 | 32 | 110 | 2018-12-01 15:10:03 |
| 54 | 12 | 213 | 2018-12-01 12:22:03 |

What I need to do is to evaluate the last 5 orders (l5o) created by the buyer_id and it's a moving l5o by each order_id. The following example is to average the last 5 order's variable_a:

| buyer_id | variable_a_avg_l5o | created_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 54 | 321.4 | 2019-06-02 |
| 54 | 242.2 | 2019-06-01 |

2019-06-02: (609+363+300+225+110)/5 = 321.4

2019-06-01: (363+300+225+110+213)/5 = 242.2

Please guide me how to apply this logic. Note that I'm using presto and correlated subqueries is not supported yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want a window function with a window frame specification:

```
select t.*,
       avg(variable_a) over (partition by buyer_id
                             order by created_date
                             rows between 4 preceding and current row
                            ) as avg_5
from t;
```